# Overall Wix methodology

Tags: wix

My ultimate goal here is to have an MSI that puts a bunch of folders and files where they need to go, and install CouchDB. Given all the dependencies and such, this is 1000+ files in a folder structure. I've gone through the Wix tutorial on firegiant's site, and I understand that the .wxs file needs to be put together correctly. I've tried scraping what I have with Heat to try to get this to work, and while I've been able to actually produce an MSI, it doesn't work and throws error 2728.

How do people normally put together an initial .wxs file for a brand new product that didn't involve Visual Studio? I can't tell if I'm missing key Heat parameters or if this is actually done by hand, which sounds insane.

Comment: You will not be able to install couchdb from msi, you will need a bootstrapper, wix provides one, called burn where you can write a nice wpf ui, or use their standard ones similar to standard setup project. A bootstrapper will execute a chain of packages, including say .net, couchdb, and then your app.

Comment: Also, when i created our installers at work i generated the files by hand to make sure i was getting sensible id names etc that made sense when it errored.. Whats the aversion to using visual studio?

Comment: I just don't think visual studio is necessary since the whole thing exists as a Node app. Would it be easier to stuff it into VS to make the installer?

Comment: When you say you generated the fileS by hand, are you saying you created multiple .wxs files for the one application installer?

Comment: no just thought you were avoiding vs by principle to build it, the benefit is you get the namespace integration but any decent text editor with the namespace detection/intellisense will make it easier. Yes i created ~12 files for 200-300 components, its not necessary given heat but it gave me greater control as there are a lot of switches for heat, your call though! Dont think theres one solution for all... However you should persist guids across iterations of the msi to facilitate upgrades. (i.e. use heat once, then update it rather than rerun)

Comment: What I'm trying to figure out is how to get from what Heat spits out to something that won't throw a 2728 when I run the MSI. I get the sense that there's a whole methodology to this that I'm unaware of, hence the posting.